# Encoding.GetString Method Example

Tags: vb.net, encoding

I'm working on a VB.Net Project with .Net Framework 4.8 and Win10 32bit. I'm trying to read a file as Binary and display the first 256 bytes in a TextBox Control on a Form.

I'm using the example from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getstring?view=netframework-4.8). I get a successful results in `Debug.WriteLine()`, **but I'm not able to display the result in `TextBox` Control.**

```
Public Class DatabaseSettings
    Const MAX_BUFFER_SIZE As Integer = 256
    Shared enc8 As Encoding = Encoding.UTF8
    Public Shared Function ThisMain(file As String) As String
        Dim fStream As New FileStream(file, FileMode.Open)
        Dim contents As String = Nothing

        ' If file size is small, read in a single operation.
        If fStream.Length <= MAX_BUFFER_SIZE Then
            Dim bytes(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1) As Byte
            fStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            contents = enc8.GetString(bytes)
            ' If file size exceeds buffer size, perform multiple reads.
        Else
            contents = ReadFromBuffer(fStream)
        End If
        fStream.Close()
        Return (contents)
    End Function

    Private Shared Function ReadFromBuffer(fStream As FileStream) As String
        Dim bytes(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE - 1) As Byte
        Dim output As String = String.Empty
        Dim decoder8 As Decoder = enc8.GetDecoder()
        Do While fStream.Position < fStream.Length
            Dim nBytes As Integer = fStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            Dim nChars As Integer = decoder8.GetCharCount(bytes, 0, nBytes)
            Dim chars(nChars - 1) As Char
            nChars = decoder8.GetChars(bytes, 0, nBytes, chars, 0)
            output += New String(chars, 0, nChars)
        Loop
        Return output
    End Function
End Class
```

Code of Form

```
Private Sub lblBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lblBrowse.Click
        TextBox1.Text = DatabaseSettings.ThisMain(LocationTxt.Text)
End Sub
```

Where **locationTxt.Text** contains the path of the File (i.e: **C:\Text\file.exe**)

Comment: The usual way to show binary data is as hexadecimal, e.g. `TextBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", yourArray.Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want bytes then read bytes. Using an encoding is specifically converting bytes to text or text to bytes. You already have bytes and bytes is what you want so there's no conversion to be done.

```vb
Const BYTE_COUNT As Integer = 256
Dim data(BYTE_COUNT - 1) As Byte

Using fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open)
    fs.Read(data, 0, BYTE_COUNT)
End Using
```

That's it. You just read the first 256 bytes of a file. As for displaying that data, you have to decide what you want the user to see. What representation of each byte do you want? If you want decimal then you just convert each `Byte` to a `String` as you normally would, e.g.

```
Dim text = String.Join(" ", data)
```

That will create a single `String` with each byte represented as a decimal number with spaces separating them. As suggested, it is customary to use hexadecimal to display binary data, because the full range of values can be represented with two digits:

```
Dim text = String.Join(" ", data.Select(Function(n) n.ToString("X2")))
```

The previous code would implicitly call `ToString` on each `Byte` and use each result. This code explicitly calls `ToString` and provides a format specifier. "X2" specifies two upper-case hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Ok, Part of the `Textbox.Text` now contains `00 01 00 00 53 74 61 6E 64 61 72 64 20 41 43 45` , and this is the signature I was expecting. How may I convert this Header dump Hex to readable Text in the another Textbox Control ?

Comment: @evry1falls Are the first 4 bytes to be ignored when converting it to text? `Dim yourString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb, 4, bb.Count - 4)` gives "Standard ACE" (where `bb` is the array of bytes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at these lines:

```
enc8.GetString(bytes)
decoder8.GetChars(...)
```

They tell .Net to interpret `bytes` as data that is **arleady** in UTF-8 format. *They do not perform any conversion.*

> I'm trying to read a file as Binary

If the file is really **binary**, and not already UTF-8 encoded characters, then treating it directly as UTF-8 is not correct. Possibly what you want to do is [Base-64 Encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string) the data instead.

Comment: One thing I would say is that base-64 is generally for storing binary data as text in a concise manner rather than for representing it in a readable manner. If you want the user to be able to read the data then hexadecimal would be more appropriate than base-64. We don't know exactly what the purpose is at this point, so I'm not saying that base-64 is wrong, but just making the distinction for the OP.

Comment: @Joel, the file is Binary (**file.accdb**)